# use latex but the matplotlib doesn't print $\Delta$

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm using matplotlib and set some things like:

```
preamblelist =  [
                    r'\usepackage{amsmath}',
                    #r'\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}',
                    r'\usepackage{siunitx}',
                    r'\sisetup{detect-all}',
                    r'\usepackage{helvet, bm}',
                    r'\usepackage{sansmath}',
                    #r'\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}',
                    r'\sansmath',
                    #r'\sisetup{detect-family = true}',
                ]

rcdict =    {
                'font.family':          'sans-serif',
                'font.sans-serif':      ['Helvetica'],
                'font.size':            18, #10 or 18
                'mathtext.fontset':     'stixsans',
                'mathtext.bf':          'stixsans:bold',
                'mathtext.it':          'stixsans:italic',
                'mathtext.rm':          'stixsans', 
                'mathtext.sf':          'stixsans',
                'text.latex.preamble':  '\n'.join(preamblelist),
                'text.usetex':          True,
            }

plt.rcParams.update(rcdict)
```

When I want to use '\Delta' as the x-label, unfortunately it cannot be printed, as shown below.

[image]

I tried to solve it and already search things online but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You also didn't include the figure of what you're currently getting.

Comment: thank you for the reminder, I already upload